# Mongoose findOne variables

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a function which passes a `key` `val` and then gets added as arguments for a `.findOne()` mongoose function.

```
getByKey = async (key, val) => {
    console.log(key, val);
    const user = await UserSchema.findOne({
        key: val
    });
    console.log(user);
    return user;
};
```

The problem is, I think mongoose is actually searching the collection for the word `key` instead of the what it stands for ie: `"username"` or `"age"`

Answer (score 0):

It is looking for 'key' as opposed to the key your passing. You can accomplish what you're trying to do by doing something like this.

```
 var query = {}
 query[key] = value;
```

And then pass that query to your `findOne` function. See below.

```
getByKey = async (key, val) => {
    var query = {}
    query[key] = value;
    const user = await UserSchema.findOne(query);
    console.log(user);
    return user;
};
```

You also might want to consider adding a callback function to in your `findOne` and try to log the data if it was found.

```
const user = await UserSchema.findOne(query, function(err, data){
    if (err){
      console.log(err)
    } else {
      console.log(data)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) to handle this. Example:

```
const user = await UserSchema.findOne({
    [key]: val
});
```